# Visual Studio 2012 SDK broken on Windows 8.1 preview

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, windows-8.1

I recently installed windows 8.1 preview as a last-ditch effort to solve my problem of Visual Studio 2012 being horribly slow. That made it run 100% faster. Unfortunately, my VS 2010-2012 extension, which is targeted for .NET 4.0 in order to run on VS 2010 AND 2012, will no longer build on Windows 8.1 preview. Several SDK dlls (e.g. Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Data.dll) are not available when targeting .NET 4.0. If I switch to .NET 4.5+, they become available to reference. Installing VS 2013 preview did not fix the problem. Any ideas on how to solve this issue are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue.  None of the Microsoft.VisualStudio classes were being found when the extension targeted 4.0 framework rather than 4.5.  In fact I started a new Extension project in VS2010 and it would not compile.

My resolution was the following:

1. uninstall the vs2010 sdk's and SP1
2. reinstall VS2010 & 2010 SDK.
3. install VS2010 SP1 and 2010 SDK SP1.

Not sure if all this was required or not, but after this I was able to build again.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to forcefully install .NET 4.0, so try following a procedure similar to [this one for .NET 3.5](http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/1147872-howto-install-net-35-in-windows-81/)

Comment: There seems to be a different procedure for .NET 4.0+. I have yet to find a way to uninstall the frameworks in order to reinstall them.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by reinstalling .NET 4.0 and 4.5. You can find them [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17718) and [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30653) for 4.0 and 4.5 respectively. Best of luck and let us know!

Comment: How did you uninstall those frameworks in order to reinstall them? The cleanup tool did not seem to work for me.

Comment: I just reinstalled them, the installer let me do it while still having them installed if I recall correctly. It doesn't do that for you?

Comment: No, it said that I already had that version or newer installed and refused to continue. I found a possible solution here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2010/05/12/10011664.aspx but I do not have any "setupcache" directories in my framework folders, so I can't run the uninstall.

Comment: http://techdows.com/2012/08/remove-net-framework-4-5-with-net-framework-cleanup-tool.html

(I haven't used this myself - no responsibility if it doesn't work :P)

Comment: I ran this utility earlier. It did not remove any files at all. In fact, I think it made the problem worse. I will probably have to reinstall windows :( ... will probably just go back to windows 7.